# Different actions depending on passed arguments: best pattern to choose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

A lot of times, I want a method to do one thing or other depending on the arguments. Given this class:

```
class SendMailJob 
  def initialize(action_to_perform, user)
    self.send(action_to_perform.to_s, args)
  end

  private
  def feedback(user)
    puts "We send feedback email #{user}"
  end
  def any_help(user)
    puts "We send any_help email #{user}"
  end
end
```

depending on what I want to do, I call it with a symbol with an option:

```
SendMailJob.new(:feedback, @user)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution is sound (as is the answer by **lx00st**), but I think I might use static methods (class methods) instead of the use case you posted.

```
class SendMailJob
  def self.feedback(user)
    puts "We send feedback email #{user}"
  end

  def self.any_help(user)
    puts "We send feedback email #{user}"
  end
end

SendMailJob.feedback(@user)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a more oop-design-patern-way you should delegate those methods to subclasses

```
class SendMailJob
  def initialize(user)
    do_action user
  end
end 

class FeedbackJob < SendMailJob
  def do_action(user)
    puts "We send feedback email #{user}"
  end
end
```

But with the power of methaprogramming it is more convenient to use "send" unless you want to separate some logic